# Conditionally redirect pages from http to https or https to http

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to edit my `.htaccess` file in order to have users go through an SSL connection for some pages, and not for others.

For example, when visiting a page called `login.php` (which sometimes is `login.php?lo=true`) they enter in their log in details. After they visit `login.php` they then proceed to `check_login.php` and if they are successful they move on to `index.php`.

My question is this: How do I change my `.htaccess` file in order for the following to occur:

- `http://www.site.com/login.php` ---> `https://www.site.com/login.php` and if there are variables such as `lo=true`
- `http://www.site.com/check_login.php` --> `https://www.site.com/check_login.php`
- Any other page that is **NOT** login.php or check_login.php to be just `http`, not `https`

My knowledge of ModRewrite rules is limited and so far I have implemented the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^login\.php?lo=true$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to worry about query strings unless you use a `?` in the replacement URL. Below are the two sets of rules you need (the second set of rules is simply the opposite of first):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule  ^(?:login\.php|check_login\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^(?:login\.php|check_login\.php)$  http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Note that I have used 302 redirects for testing. Do not forget to change to 301.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put the query string in the regex in a rule, only the URI gets matched against, not the query string. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^check_login\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(check_)?login\.php
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: As far as I know, `HTTPS` will be `on` or not set. I have not seen `off`.

Comment: @SalmanA At least since [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), *"Will contain the text "on" if the connection is using SSL/TLS, or "off" otherwise."*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I gave this a try however I did prefer that @SalmanA did it in 4 lines instead of 7